# Field validation in COBOL/CICS

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I'm editing some source code for my college Transaction Processing course. We're working with COBOL/CICS, and the program is a video tape rental system. We have a list of changes to make, and one item has me stuck (it's been since Fall semester of 2010 since I took the COBOL course, so unfortunately I'm far more rusty than I should be). There is a "customer maintenance" section, in which the user can add new customers. One of the items for a new customer is the zip code, and as it stands it will take any input as valid input, but we need to make it accept only numeric values (which I do know how to do) as well as a specific format: Either '12345', '123456789', or '12345-6789', and should only write to the record as '12345' or '12345-6789'. Anything else, such as '1234' or 12345-6' will result in an error. How do I check these fields for the proper format?

Comment: Lol. It's some dated code that the instructor has recycled over the years with new exercises every now and then. I think he mentioned it came with an old textbook for the course. Give it a few years, when he assigns it there will be a student in the room who asks, "Wait, what's a video 'tape?'"

Answer (score 1):

Since the valid data format is fixed, it is easy.

```
05  nice-name-for-zip-code pic x(10).
05  filler redefines nice-name-for-zip-code.
    10  simple-zip-first-part pic x(5).
    10  simple-zip-last-part pic x(5).
        88  simple-zip-last-part-valid value space.
05  filler redefines nice-name-for-zip-code.
    10  complex-zip-first-part pic x(5).
    10  complex-zip-separator pic x.
        88  complex-zip-separator value "-".
    10  complex-zip-last-part pic x(4).
05  filler redefines nice-name-for-zip-code.
    10  long-zip-first-part pic x(9).
    10  long-zip-last-part pic x. 
        88  long-zip-last-part-valid value space.

if ( simple-zip-first-part numeric )
and ( simple-zip-last-part-valid )
    ....

if ( complex-zip-first-part numeric )
and ( complex-zip-separator-valid )
and ( complex-zip-last-part numeric )
    ....

if ( long-zip-first-part numeric )
and ( long-zip-last-part-valid )
    ....
```

If any of the IFs is true, you have a valid format. Otherwise, invalid.

Comment: simple-zip-last-part can be 4 digit numeric as well.  Also, if it's a simple 9 digit zip, it has to be formatted with a dash.

Comment: Thanks Gilbert. I missed the 9-digit one in the description, and got an 88-name wrong. I've now covered what is in the question. I have no actual knowledge of US Zip Codes, if anything as described in the requirement is unrealistic, I'm not sure that it matters from the point of the exercise. A four-digit number *can* be handled, and if the nine-digit must really be presented as the 5-dash-4, then that can be for Cory to sort out.

Comment: Sorry Bill, I didn't know you were unfamiliar with US zip codes.  I just wanted to give you the opportunity to fix your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach might be to let CICS BMS support do most of the
validation and editing for you. This assumes you are using a 3270 type
terminal with CICS (which is probably the case)

Try setting the Zip Code up as a group field on the BMS map. This has the effect
of creating a single input field with multiple parts to it.

Your BMS Map definition would look something like:

```
 ZIP1     DFHMDF POS=(2,1),LENGTH=5,GRPNAME=ZIP,ATTRB=(UNPROT,NUM)
 SEP      DFHMDF POS=(2,6),LENGTH=1,GRPNAME=ZIP,ATTRB=(ASKIP,NORM),INITIAL='-'
 ZIP2     DFHMDF POS=(2,7),LENGTH=5,GRPNAME=ZIP,ATTRB=(UNPROT,NUM),JUSTIFY=(LEFT,BLANK)
```

The Zip code will appear at the beginning of line 2 (POS=(2..)). It will have a 5 digit input
field (ZIP1) for the first part of the Zip Code, followed by a hard coded input protected 
dash (SEP) and another left justified 5
digit blank filled input field (ZIP2) for the last part of the Zip code.

From this point on, BMS will force the user to enter 5 digits into the first part of the Zip Code,
cannot touch the dash and optionally enter zero to 5 digits in the second part of
the input field. None of these fields will accept non-numeric data (except the SEP, which is input protected)

When you retrieve the data from the screen all you need to do is check to see
if ZIP2 is numeric to figure out if a long or short Zip code was entered. If
a long Zip, then store the whole thing, if short, only store ZIP1.

Comment: If just "1" is entered into ZIP1, isn't it going to give "00001" as the result?

Comment: @BillWoodger Yes it would - if that isn't what you want, then use `JUSTIFY=(LEFT,BLANK)` for both ZIP1 and ZIP2 and test for numeric: If ZIP1 not numeric then invalid. If ZIP2 not numeric then short zip, otherwise long zip. I find this approach a lot easier to follow than a stack of `REDEFINES` and 88 levels.

Comment: Since it is a CICS exercise, a good example. It doesn't deal with the nine-digit requirement as stated, but that part of the requirement is probably "wrong". For a video-store, I'd really expect a "range" of valid zip-codes anyway, as a store in Kansas City (for example) is unlikely to want renters from Texas. For input in a "store", it is much better to have the "-" automatically. Again for "bulk" input, with the "-" pre-printed on the data-entry form. But only a class exercise...

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the CICS command BIF DEEDIT, which will remove non-numeric chars, the minus passes that test.  After that, test for a length of 5 or 10.

Or, you could use an 88 like this:

```
01 Zip-Validation-Field.
 02 filler pic x(5).
  88 Zip-Valid value '00000' thru '99999'.
 02 filler pic x(5).
  88 Zip-plus-4-valid value '-0000' thru '-9999'.
```

And test with:

```
If Zip-Valid and Zip-plus-4-valid...
```

Comment: No. Like that "0AAAA" is valid, as is "9ZZZZ", similar with the second 88. The digits, the group of five, then a group of four, must be tested for NUMERIC as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MOVE CORR

```
 01 TX-ZIPCODE          PIC X(08) VALUE '    -   '.
 01 TX-ZIPCODE-R REDEFINES TX-ZIPCODE.
    03 ZIPCODE-P1       PIC 9(04).
    03 FILLER           PIC X(01).
    03 ZIPCODE-P2       PIC 9(03).
 01 NUM-ZIPCODE         PIC X(07).
 01 NUM-ZIPCODE-R REDEFINES NUM-ZIPCODE.
    03 ZIPCODE-P1       PIC 9(04).
    03 ZIPCODE-P2       PIC 9(03).




 MOVE CORR TX-ZIPCODE-R TO NUM-ZIPCODE-R.

 IF NUM-ZIPCODE IS NOT NUMERIC
*     ERRO
 END-IF.
```

Hope I have help you! :)

Comment: Won't work when ZIPCODE-P2 contains blanks, which is valid. I dislike `MOVE CORR` as the next person along always has to look at what is included in the MOVE before knowing,